# Can't make any sort of Database type connecction on Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: java, database, netbeans, database-connection, netbeans-8

I have spent hours looking through forums and other help sites to try to find a solution to my problem. I've tried a countless number of things to try and fix it, but it's still not working. I've pretty much come to the conclusion that my NetBeans program cannot make any sort of connection beyond opening programs. You see this started when I tried to create a new database. Well the window opened, I filled out the information, and then I got an error that said "An error occurred while creating the database: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:java.net.ConnectionException : Error connectingto server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection timed out: connect.."

I then tried to connect to the sample database that comes with Netbeans and even that database wouldn't connect. I've tried everything and really need some help.

Before you ask, yes I have opened the port, yes I tried changing the security file as some have suggested, yes I have tried making a new connection(which didn't even work by the way), yes I have tried creating a database through coding in a project (didn't work), and yes I have played around with the proxy setting in Tools>Options>General.

Comment: Is this on a windows system? Are you able to connect on the port with another program outside of netbeans?

Comment: Have you included the database driver jars specific to the database you use?